# Какую библиотеку нужно подключить к js, чтобы сортировались даты

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

У меня указана это http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/sorts/tablesort.date.js . Но из-за того что там месяца на английском, а у меня на русском, ничего не сортируется.

```
    <script src="http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/sorts/tablesort.number.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tristen.ca/tablesort/src/sorts/tablesort.date.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    new Tablesort(document.getElementById('table-id'));
});
```

Comment: может не в русском дело?. Вы <script src='tablesort.min.js'></script> такой скрипт не подключаете? он ведь, мне думается, нужен для данной библиотеки. вот он https://github.com/tristen/tablesort/blob/master/dist/tablesort.min.js и потом уже  tablesort.date.js подключать

Comment: попробовала так, ничего не получилось

Comment: таблица содержит еще столбцы? по ним сортировка работает? таблица имеет идишник table-id? мало информации вы выложили...Для начала попробуйте прикрутить библиотеку, что-бы сортировка по какому-нибудь столбцу работала. Тогда хоть будет уверенность, что библиотека подключена..А потом уже смотреть даты будет сортировать или нет.

Comment: таблица столбцы содержит, сортировка работает по всем столбцам, кроме "дата".

Comment: а какой формат у данных столбца "дата"? может его переделать в dd.mm.YYYY? такой формат по идее должен быть подхвачен библиотекой. Или нельзя править данные таблицы?

Comment: у меня нет возможности меня формат данных которые передаются в бд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я так и не увидел возможный формат русских дат, но немного подшаманил скрипт `tablesort.date.js`:

```
    // Basic dates in dd/mm/yy or dd-mm-yy format.
// Years can be 4 digits. Days and Months can be 1 or 2 digits.
(function(){
  var parseDate = function(date) {
    date = date.replace(/\-/g, '/');
    date = date.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{2,4})/, '$3-$2-$1'); // format before getTime
    
    date = date.replace(/января/i, 'Jan');
    date = date.replace(/февраля/i, 'Feb');
    date = date.replace(/марта/i, 'Mar');
    date = date.replace(/апреля/i, 'Apr');
    date = date.replace(/мая/i, 'May');
    date = date.replace(/июня/i, 'Jun');
    date = date.replace(/июля/i, 'Jul');
    date = date.replace(/августа/i, 'Aug');
    date = date.replace(/сентября/i, 'Sep');
    date = date.replace(/октября/i, 'Oct');
    date = date.replace(/ноября/i, 'Nov');
    date = date.replace(/декабря/i, 'Dec');
    date = date.replace(/г\. /i, '');
    return new Date(date).getTime() || -1;
  };

  Tablesort.extend('date', function(item) {
    return (
      item.search(/(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\.?\,?\s*/i) !== -1 ||
      item.search(/\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{2,4}/) !== -1 ||
      item.search(/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)/i) !== -1 ||
      item.search(/(Января|Февраля|Марта|Апреля|Мая|Июня|Июля|Августа|Сентября|Октября|Ноября|Декабря)/i) !== -1
    ) && !isNaN(parseDate(item));
  }, function(a, b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();

    return parseDate(b) - parseDate(a);
  });
}());
```

у меня даты в которых встречаются полные русские именования месяцев (типа `15 Января 1990`) теперь сортирует вроде(мало тестил) верно. Проверьте на своем датасете и, возможно, в столбце даты у вас другой формат. Поправил под формат типа `01 Января 1990 г. 11:00`.

Comment: А куда и как правильно это функцию вставлять?

Comment: ну можете выложить данный код где-нибудь в интернете, назвать файл tablesort.date.js, к примеру..и ссылку на него вставлять. Только учтите кодировку символов отдаваемых сервером. Либо, если вы можете править html где вы ссылки вставляете, напрямую вставить данный код между тегами <script>код</script>, а ссылку на файл убрать.

Comment: Попробовала 2 способ, ничего не получилось, перестали сортироваться все колонки

Comment: не знаю тогда, что-то где-то не так сделано. один файл то, tablesort.js надо импортировать. после него функцию. можно посмотреть на консоль яваскрипта (cntrl+shift+I, там она) на предмет сообщений.

Comment: А где можно выложить данный код в интернете?

Comment: ну я у себя выложил, временно конечно, https://stepanoff.ru/tablesort.date.js попробуйте, но мне кажется не заработает, потому что кодировка символов сp1251, а не utf8 отдаваемая сервером, я не смог щас изменить ее почему-то.

Comment: К сожалению, нет. Вот так сортирует https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1418869/Не-правильно-сортирует-даты-js-в-django

Comment: ну так я вас просил давно привести мне пример ваших данных из сортируемой колонки дата. Если на ссылке ваша колонка то сейчас я попробую под нее подправить.. там же еще г. на русском.

Comment: хорошо, буду ждать

Comment: поправил, в ссылке https://stepanoff.ru/tablesort.date.js измененный вариант. только на странице cntr+f5 нажмите, дабы кеш обновить. У меня локально сортирует записи в вашем формате.

Comment: а None - в столбце Data ? наверно нет..

Comment: а если текстом вставить, только у меня нет исправленного вида

Comment: я поправил, можете выше взять итоговую функцию

Comment: Теперь заработало, спасибо!!!